# How to provide a BLoC (with flutter_bloc) to `showSearch`

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using the package `flutter_bloc` for state management. I want to create a search screen, and found the `showSearch` Flutter function, and have been having issues providing a `BLoC` instance to the `ListView` my `SearchDelegate` implementation creates. I finally made it work, but would like to ask what the best way of doing this is. Here is the code (excerpts, starting from a button that is placed in an `AppBar` within a `Scaffold`):

```dart
class ItemSearchButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
      onPressed: () {
        final itemListBloc = context.bloc<ItemListBloc>();
        showSearch(
          context: context,
          delegate: _ItemSearchDelegate(itemListBloc),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _ItemSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final ItemListBloc itemListBloc;

  _ItemSearchDelegate(this.itemListBloc);

  // other overridden methods

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider.value(
      value: itemListBloc,
      child: ItemListWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, the context that invokes the `showSearch` method has the correct BLoC instance, but it is not available within my `SearchDelegate` implementation, unless I re-provide it again explicitly in `buildSuggestions`.

Why is the BLoC not available by default? The `showSearch` function internally pushes a new `Navigator` `Route`, is this the issue?

What is the canonical way of dealing with things like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it works as intended - the pushed route has a new context that is *not* a child of a context that has my BLoC, it is a child of the `Navigator`. The solution is to either do what I did initially - pass the BLoC explicitly as constructor argument - or make sure the `Navigator` context has the BLoCs, which is what I eventually did; to do this, make sure the `Navigator` is a child of the `(Multi)BlocProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the route changes, `buildContext`changes too. So you have to provide that bloc to the new context. Just wrap your page where you want to navigate with `BlocProvider`:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => 
BlocProvider(create: Mybloc(),child:MyPage());
```

Comment: The problem is the navigation is performed by the `showSearch` function, i.e. I can't change it. I already do what you are saying for my own routes without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DiscoverSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
final AppSearchBloc appSearchBloc = AppSearchBloc();
....
}
```

and then use Bloc provider+builder to show changes

```
@override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    appSearchBloc.add(AppSearchEvent.changeQuery(query));
    return BlocProvider.value(
      value: appSearchBloc,
      child: BlocBuilder<AppSearchBloc, AppSearchState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return SearchHistory(
            state.searchStory,
            onSearch: (value) {
              query = value;
              // showResults(context);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is good advice. `buildSuggestions` is called from `build`, which is supposed not to have side effects, and you are sending events to `appSearchBloc` there, which triggers them.

Comment: I just found an example in bloc docs [Using bloc with SearchDelegate](https://gist.github.com/felangel/11769ab10fbc4076076299106f48fc95)